# Constructing JSON object using PL/SQL collection object

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a collection object in PL/SQL containing nested tables.  Is there a way to create a JSON object based on this collection within PL/SQL without iterating through all of the nested tables within the collection?  I know there is the PLJSON package out there but it looks to me like I would have to iterate through the object to create the JSON object.  I could be wrong and will continue to research this route.  However, if anybody has actual experience in creating a JSON object based on an existing PL/SQL collection, I would appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I don't think there is any "native" json support in oracle for the behavior you are looking for.  How else would you access the data if you don't iterate through it?

Comment: I was hoping I could just define the json structure and then pass an Oracle collection and the json schema definition to a function, and it would return the data in the format I defined in the json schema.  Guess that's too much to ask for.

Comment: You can use the Java programming interface and existing json libraries to do this if you really don't want to redo it.